# Why does my code return "Unexpected token ="?

Tags: typescript, discord, discord.js

I am working on Discord.TS bot but when I launch it with `ts-node src/index.ts`, I see the error

```
/home/negative/Dev/JS/Bot/src/structures/Client.ts:10
    commands = new discord_js_1.Collection();
             ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token =
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:23)
    at Module.m._compile (/home/negative/Dev/JS
...
```

Here is my code (Client.ts)

```ts
import {
    ApplicationCommandDataResolvable,
    Client,
    ClientEvents,
    Collection
} from "discord.js";
import { CommandType } from "../typings/Command";
import glob from "glob";
import { promisify } from "util";
import { RegisterCommandsOptions } from "../typings/client";
import { Event } from "./Event";

const globPromise = promisify(glob);
export class ExtendedClient extends Client {
    commands: Collection<string, CommandType> = new Collection();

    constructor() {
        super({ intents: 32767 });
    }

    start() {
        this.registerModules();
        this.login(process.env.botToken);
    }
    async importFile(filePath: string) {
        return (await import(filePath))?.default;
    }

    async registerCommands({ commands, guildId }: RegisterCommandsOptions) {
        if (guildId) {
            this.guilds.cache.get(guildId)?.commands.set(commands);
            console.log(`Registering commands to ${guildId}`);
        } else {
            this.application?.commands.set(commands);
            console.log("Registering global commands");
        }
    }

    async registerModules() {
        // Commands
        const slashCommands: ApplicationCommandDataResolvable[] = [];
        const commandFiles = await globPromise(
            `${__dirname}/../commands/*/*{.ts,.js}`
        );
        commandFiles.forEach(async (filePath) => {
            const command: CommandType = await this.importFile(filePath);
            if (!command.name) return;
            console.log(command);

            this.commands.set(command.name, command);
            slashCommands.push(command);
        });

        this.on("ready", () => {
            this.registerCommands({
                commands: slashCommands,
                guildId: process.env.guildId
            });
        });

        // Event
        const eventFiles = await globPromise(
            `${__dirname}/../events/*{.ts,.js}`
        );
        eventFiles.forEach(async (filePath) => {
            const event: Event<keyof ClientEvents> = await this.importFile(
                filePath
            );
            this.on(event.event, event.run);
        });
    }
}
```

The Visual Studio Code says that my code has no errors, but I can not fix this one. Can someone please tell me how to fix it? I have been working on this problem...
If you know  how to fix this, please tell, I will be really please to you.

Comment: We need to be able to see Client.ts - that is where the error is.

Comment: @phuzi the code I gave here is from Client.ts

Comment: I can't see the line `commands = new discord_js_1.Collection();` in that code. Perhaps the error is in the compiled JavaScript. Can you show us that too?

Comment: I think `commands = new discord_js_1.Collection();` is `commands: Collection<string, CommandType> = new Collection();` translated from typescript to js because there is no `commands = new discord_js_1.Collection();` string in my code.

Comment: What js version are you targeting? What node.js version do you have? Likely you are targeting a js version that isn't supported by your node.js version. Make sure to update your node.js version to the latest one.

Comment: I reinstalled the node js and it worked! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is because you are targeting a JavaScript version that isn't supported by your installed Node.js version. You can either change the JavaScript version you are targeting, or update your Node.js version.

### Option 1: Updating Node.js Version

Make sure you have installed at least Node.js version `16.11.0` (according to [node.green](https://node.green/#ES2022-features-instance-class-fields) this is the first version to fully support [instance class fields](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields)).

You can check your node version by typing `node -v` in your terminal.

```
$ node -v
v17.1.0
```

You can then install the latest Node.js version from their website: https://nodejs.org/

### Option 2: Changing Target JavaScript Version

Open your `tsconfig.json` file and change the [target field](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#target) to a version that is supported by your current Node.js version.

You can check your node version by typing `node -v` in your terminal.

```
$ node -v
v17.1.0
```

Consult [node.green](https://node.green/) to determine what JavaScript version you can target based on your current Node.js version.

Comment: when I updated node, every time I interacted with `npm`, it said `Error: Cannot find module 'semver'`

Comment: @wowkoltyy have you installed the `semver` package?

Comment: I do not know what is it

Comment: @wowkoltyy `semver` is an npm package, you are getting an error saying that some code you are trying to run expects `semver` to be installed, but its not installed, so the program crashes. What npm command are you trying to run?

Comment: I tried to run `npm run start` and `npm i semver`. Both of this returned error. https://i.imgur.com/G55Selr.png

Comment: @wowkoltyy what npm version do you have? run `npm -version`

Comment: I can't. Every single time I enter `npm` to terminal it returns this error.

Comment: @wowkoltyy what node version did you have before updating?

Comment: I don't remember. I think I had v12 of node and v6 of npm.

Comment: @wowkoltyy might be an issue with your installation. Try removing node from the machine and clean installing the latest LTS version